# update old javascript function to jquery function not working snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update this Javascript function to Jquery, I need to use it with `on("input",function...`

This is a realtime search function....

This is a basic form but is useful, the problem comes when I try to reset the input with Jquery `.val("")` and this clears it but not the search results...
so It needs update.

I tried this but is not working

```
$("#search_emotions").on("input",function(){
 var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
 input = $("search_emotions");
 filter = input.val();
 ul = $("emotions");
   li = $("emotions li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].find("div")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
}


 });
```

```js
function SearchEmotions() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("search_emotions");
    filter = input.value;
    ul = document.getElementById("emotions");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type=text id='search_emotions' onkeyup="SearchEmotions();" placeholder="Search emotions" />

<ul class="emotions" id="emotions">
<li ><div class="emotion_1">A</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_2">B</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_3">CF</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_4">DE</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_5">E</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_6">FA</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_7">GB</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_8">HC</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are missing Id selecteor in this line ```input = $("search_emotions");``` Add ID selector. ```input = $("#search_emotions");```. Same issue in other selectors as well

Comment: ill check it out,

Comment: FYI - jQuery is not an upgrade. You added over 10,000 lines of code to use 4 features.

Comment: true but this is the current plugin I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check updated

```js
$("#search_emotions").on("input",function(){
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = $("#search_emotions");
  filter = input.val();
  ul = $("#emotions");
   
  ul.find('li').each(function(){
      var a = $(this).find("div").text();
      if( a.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          $(this).css("display", "");
      } else {
          $(this).css("display", "none");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id='search_emotions'  placeholder="Search emotions" />

<ul class="emotions" id="emotions">
<li ><div class="emotion_1">A</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_2">B</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_3">CF</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_4">DE</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_5">E</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_6">FA</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_7">GB</div></li>
<li ><div class="emotion_8">HC</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues here...

- In jQuery, the equivalent of `document.getElementById("emotions")` is `$('#emotions')`. When you use, for example, `$("emotions")`, it will look for `<emotions>` elements, instead of by Id.
- Inside your for, when you use `li[i]`, it is not a jQuery element, so you can't use `li[i].find`. To transform to a jQuery element, you can use: a) `li.eq(i)`, or b) `$(li[i])`.

There is a working example, very similar to the one that you posted:

```js
$("#search_emotions").on("input", function(){
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = $(this);
    filter = input.val();
    ul = $("#emotions");
    li = $("#emotions li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li.eq(i).find("div")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id='search_emotions' placeholder="Search emotions" />

<ul class="emotions" id="emotions">
  <li ><div class="emotion_1">A</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_2">B</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_3">CF</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_4">DE</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_5">E</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_6">FA</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_7">GB</div></li>
  <li ><div class="emotion_8">HC</div></li>
</ul>
```

PS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49685340/2056593 has a more "jquery" way example.